# Sanatize html on server in schema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I've installed `mpowaga:autoform-summernote`, `djedi:sanitize-html` to try and clean the data going into `simpleschema` however I'm not sure how I get it to work. I only want the users to be able to add 'p' and 'a' tags plus bold and italic style. What am I doing wrong here?

```
description: {
       type: String,  
        optional: true,
        autoform: {             
            afFieldInput: {
                type: 'summernote', 
                class: 'editor',
                settings: {
                    allowedTags: ['p', 'a'],
                    toolbar: [
                        ['style', ['bold', 'italic']],
                        ['para', ['ul', 'ol']]
                      ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.

To start to answer your question, I don't think you can do the sanitize inside of your `SimpleSchema` (although I hope I'm wrong because that would be easiest). From what I can tell, that settings object is for **summer-note's** options... e.g. what will be shown on the toolbar. I don't think that object is where you can use the `djedi:sanitize-html` functionality :

http://summernote.org/deep-dive/
https://github.com/mpowaga/meteor-autoform-summernote/issues/16

This GitHub issue seems to suggest the sanitize should go inside some sort of before hook:

https://github.com/mpowaga/meteor-autoform-summernote/issues/13

However, I thought autoform hooks were client-side and so `djedi:sanitize-html` won't work there. There is a client-side version (`djedi:sanitize-html-client`) but I'm not sure if that's unsecure and defeats the purpose of sanitizing in the first place?

Personally, I'm using autoform's that insert with a method call. I'll report back if I solve it.

Further Reading:

- https://forums.meteor.com/t/ckeditor-outputs-html-how-to-convert-it-for-saving/5981/3
- https://forums.meteor.com/t/template-helpers-and-collection/2223/3
- https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-strike-podcast-episode-8-djedi-sanitize-html/17921

Comment: Put a console statement in the autovalue hook to see if it runs on the server.  Almost certain it does.

Edit: Misread, autoform hooks only run on the client.  The autovalue simple schema hook runs on both cliet and server.

Comment: how did you go with this @A.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting allowed tags in the summernote settings will only work client side, and won't be secure.  You need something like this to sanitize on the server.

```
description: {
       type: String,  
        optional: true,
        autoValue: function(){
          return Meteor.isServer ? sanitizeHtml( this.value ) : this.value;
        },
        autoform: {             
            afFieldInput: {
                type: 'summernote', 
                class: 'editor',
                settings: ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks ,jimmiebltr this is look promising. How do you set the allowed values ,for instance only allow font size 16px or font type <p>?

Comment: You're going to have trouble setting style's that are allowed, it's more difficult to sanatize css in inline-styles.

Find the docs for the rest here though https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html